# How to persist tabs when using BottomNavigationBar?

Tags: flutter

Whenever I switch from Tab 1 to Tab 2 then back to Tab 1, content on Tab 1 is rebuilt. Anyway to prevent this?

Comment: provide the code.

Comment: yes, check - `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html

Comment: @anmol.majhail I already used that, still the same

Comment: share the code then.

Comment: What do you mean by rebuilt? Is it `build()` method calling again?

Comment: @anmol.majhail I think I found the problem, my current solution is to wrap all my pages with Offstage and TickerMode, change the value based on the selectedIndex, then put all the pages into Stack

Comment: I posted my solution below

Answer (score 0):

```
class BottomNavBarExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  BottomNavBarExampleState createState() {
    return new BottomNavBarExampleState();
  }
}

class BottomNavBarExampleState extends State<BottomNavBarExample> {
  List<BottomNavigationBarItem> _tabs = [
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.library_books), title: Text('Library')),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.public), title: Text('Public')),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person), title: Text('Account')),
  ];

  var _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Demo')),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: this._currentIndex,
        items: this._tabs,
        onTap: (value) {
          setState(() {
            this._currentIndex = value;
          });
        },
      ),
      body: Stack(children: [
        new Offstage(
          offstage: this._currentIndex != 0,
          child: new TickerMode(
            enabled: this._currentIndex == 0,
            child: LibraryPage(),
          ),
        ),
        new Offstage(
          offstage: this._currentIndex != 1,
          child: new TickerMode(
            enabled: this._currentIndex == 1,
            child: GalleryPage(),
          ),
        ),
        new Offstage(
          offstage: this._currentIndex != 2,
          child: new TickerMode(
            enabled: this._currentIndex == 2,
            child: AccountPage(),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Then for each page, include `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`